# Unable to update NSTouchBar programmatically

Tags: swift, macos, swift4, macos-mojave, nstouchbar

I am currently developing a very simple Live Scores MAC OSX app for personal use where I show a bunch of labels (scores) on the touch bar. What I am trying to achieve in a few steps:

1. Fetch live soccer scores from a 3rd party API every 30 seconds
2. Parse the scores and make them into labels
3. Update the touch bar with new scores

**[Please note here that this app will not be published anywhere, and is only for personal use. I am aware of the fact that Apple strictly advises against such type of content in the Touch Bar.]**

Here is the code that I wrote following basic Touch Bar tutorial from RW (https://www.raywenderlich.com/883-how-to-use-nstouchbar-on-macos). Skeleton of my code is picked from the RW tutorial:

1. In `WindowController` (StoryBoard entry point), override `makeTouchBar` like this:

```
override func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar? {
    guard let viewController = contentViewController as? ViewController else {
      return nil
    }
    return viewController.makeTouchBar()
  }
```

2. In `ViewController`, which is also the Touch Bar Delegate, implement the `makeTouchBar` fn:

```
override func makeTouchBar() -> NSTouchBar? {
    let touchBar = NSTouchBar()
    touchBar.delegate = self
    touchBar.customizationIdentifier = .scoresBar
    touchBar.defaultItemIdentifiers = [.match1, .flexibleSpace, .match2, ... , .match10]

    return touchBar
  }
```

3. `NSTouchBarDelegate` in `ViewController`. `scores` is where I store my fetched scores (See 5). I return `nil` for views if scores aren't fetched yet:

```
extension ViewController: NSTouchBarDelegate {

    func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItem.Identifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {

        if (<scores not fetched yet>) {
            return nil
        }
        // matchNum is the match number for which I am showing scores for
        let customViewItem = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
        customViewItem.view = NSTextField(labelWithString: self.scores[matchNum ?? 0])
        return customViewItem
    }
}
```

4. To fetch scores periodically I am running a scheduled task Timer in `viewDidLoad()` of my viewcontroller like this:

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 30.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.fetchScores), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

5. And finally, this is my `fetchScores` function that also makes a call to update the Touch Bar:

```
@objc func fetchScores() {
    let url = "<scores api end point>"
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in
        if let json = response.result.value {
            // update self.scores here and fill it with latest scores

            if #available(OSX 10.12.2, *) {
                //self.touchBar = nil
                self.touchBar = self.makeTouchBar() // This is where I am calling makeTouchBar again to update Touch Bar content dynamically
            }

        }
    }
```

My understanding from the code above is that once I make a call to `makeTouchBar` in `fetchScores` and assign it to my viewcontroller's `touchBar` property, it should ideally call `touchBar(:makeItemForIdentifier)` delegate function to update the Touch Bar view ([SO thread on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759909/update-nstouchbar-on-the-fly-to-add-remove-items-programmatically/)). But in my case, `touchBar(:makeItemForIdentifier)` is never called. The only time `touchBar(:makeItemForIdentifier)` is called is the first time, when `makeTouchBar` is called from my WindowController (See point 1 above). And since scores have not been retrieved yet, my touch bar remains empty.