# Hide NSTouchBar button

Tags: swift, nsbutton, nstouchbar, nscontrol

I'm working on a personal project in swift (for macOS app) and I want to make a NSbutton (Touch Bar button) and hide it. 
 
Is there a possible way to do this?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759909/update-nstouchbar-on-the-fly-to-add-remove-items-programmatically) hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer! 
Just write:

```
<button_name>.isHidden = true
```

or if you want to disable and not hide:

```
<button_name>.isEnabled = false
```

In my case I had button that called "submitButton" so I wrote:

```
submitButton.isHidden = true
```

and when I wanted it to appear I wrote:

```
submitButton.isHidden = false
```